# android: develop an app which automatically generate graph from regular expression

Tags: regex, android-studio, auto-generate, automata, finite-automata

im a beginner and i want to build an android app that will generate a graph based on a regular expression(automata) but i dont know how to do it or what kind of tool should i use. im currently using android studio. thank you for your advance response. hope you can help me :(

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a library because this cannot be done in 3 lines of code.

Comment: thank you for your response. but is it possible for me to generate a graph using android studio?? and what should i use?

Comment: You can use primitive shapes, lines, etc. But there is no built-in functionality for such specialized graph.

Comment: ah okay. thank you very much for your response.

Comment: last question, what software should i use to develop an app as well it will be possible for me to make a generator for regular expression to finite automata ? i badly need to make one

Comment: I do not know your business requirement but Android Studio/Java or HTML5/Javascript should be fine.

Comment: i want to build an app that will generate a map/machine for Finite automata. but i dont kknow if it is possible for me to generate some patterns, or maps. :(

Comment: Interesting question. I will follow your thread. look at this link. http://automatonsimulator.com/

Comment: Any graph could be represented by matrix. so you can see that which node is connected to which node. for the DFA/NFA this matrix is sparse.

Comment: Does using sparse can generate shapes?